# If you don't have me you will face

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> On many minds of the human race
> If you do not have me you will face
> Turning me high at a feeding place
> Being considered a family disgrace

Hint *(upon request)*

> Fast

Comment: Hint, please? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer:

> HAIR

On many minds of the human race

> literally above your mind on the top of your head. And a huge topic of fashion.

If you do not have me you will face

> A pun. If you have no hair, we can see your entire face - not covered by a beard, moustache, locks, etc

Turning me high at a feeding place

> Hair must be worn high if you are serving in a restaurant or *fast* food establishment

Being considered a family disgrace

> Hair is often a source of drama, there have been high profile news stories lately about it especially in schools, but I believe what this is really getting at is a well known but unusual quotation:
>  "Does not nature itself teach you that if a man wears long hair it is a disgrace for him" - 1 Cor. 11:14  (and similarly women can experience similar disgraces if missing hair, e.g. v6 "But since it is disgraceful for a wife to cut off her hair or shave her head...")

Re hint:

> Fast food (above) and it grows fast, especially when the barber shops were closed.